# R regular expression: using \\b with 'Å' vs. 'A' characters

Tags: r, regex

`\\b` represents a word boundary. I don't understand why this operator has different effects depending on the character that follows. Example:

```
test1 <- 'aland islands'
test2 <- 'åland islands'

regex1 <- "[å|a]land islands"
regex2 <- "\\b[å|a]land islands"

grepl(regex1, test1, perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
grepl(regex2, test1, perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE

grepl(regex1, test2, perl = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
grepl(regex2, test2, perl = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

This only seems to be an issue when `perl = TRUE`:

```
grepl(regex1, test2, perl = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
grepl(regex2, test2, perl = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Unfortunately, in my application, I absolutely need to keep `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: I can't confirm: `grepl("\\b[å|a]land islands", "åland islands", perl = TRUE)` returns `TRUE` for me.

Comment: @MauritsEvers you are using Windows?

Comment: @wp78de I'm on MacOS and Linux.

Comment: I cant produce the error. i am on windows

Comment: As @wp78de points out in their answer, the nasty thing about this behavior is that it is inconsistent across platforms. When I saw you couldn't reproduce, I tried different things: The weird behavior arises in the Docker environment I usually use, but not when I run R straight from terminal on osx. This is annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a (known) glitch in R's regex subsystem and is related to the character encoding of the input and the system locale / built properties.

The R documentation on [grep](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/grep) states (highlighting added):

> The POSIX 1003.2 mode of gsub and gregexpr does not work correctly
>   with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., pattern = "\b"). Use perl = TRUE
>   for such matches (**but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII
>   inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent**).

Only `gsub` and `grepexpr` are mentioned here `grepl` seems to be affected as well.

#### Possible soutions

- using R's default ([TRE reference](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/blob/master/doc/tre-syntax.html)) regex engine: `PERL=FALSE` as already discovered by you.
- stick with the PCRE ([reference](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)) regex using the `*UCP` flag (Unicode mode|Unicode Character Properties), which changes the matching behavior so that Unicode alphanumerics are not considered as word boundaries:

  Code Sample:

  ```
  options(encoding = "UTF-8")

  test1 <- 'aland islands'
  test2 <- 'åland islands'
  regex1 <- "[å|a]land islands"
  regex2 <- "(*UCP)\\b[å|a]land islands"    
  grepl(regex1, test2, perl = TRUE)
  #[1] TRUE
  grepl(regex2, test2, perl = TRUE)
  #[1] TRUE
  grepl(regex1, test2, perl = TRUE)
  #[1] TRUE
  grepl(regex2, test2, perl = TRUE)
  #[1] TRUE
  grepl(regex1, test2, perl = FALSE)
  #[1] TRUE
  grepl(regex2, test2, perl = FALSE)
  #[1] FALSE
  ```

  [**Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/xfrVzQ)

  Notes:

  - The 6th test, using TRE with the (*UCP) flag, fails `grepl(regex2, test2, perl = FALSE)`
  - The `*UCP` flag does not work if R is not installed with Unicode support for PCRE (may be the case in [some environments](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/311), e.g. some minimal Cloud/Docker installations).

---

What's really annoying is that R's behavior is inconsistent across platforms:

- Works as expected on current 64bit Windows (10)
- May work on current Linux distros

Test your original code with these online R environments:

- [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php) or
- [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MVDCGD)

  Only test case 4 is FALSE: `gepl(regex2, test2, perl = TRUE)`
  (Running R 3.3/3.4 on Linux?)
- [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-r-online)

  Test case 4 and 6 are FALSE
  (Running R 3.3-3.5 on Linux?)

---

Further readings:

- Check out some more differences of [regular expressions in base R: 'perl=TRUE' vs. the default (PCRE vs. TRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47251004/8291949)
- Related: [Strange behaviour of regex in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909521/strange-behaviour-of-regex-in-r)
- [How to change the locale of R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347731/how-to-change-the-locale-of-r) (does not help here, just as a back reference for others)
- [gsub with perl=TRUE results in 'this version of PCRE is not compiled with Unicode property support' in R-devel](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/gsub-with-perl-TRUE-results-in-this-version-of-PCRE-is-not-compiled-with-Unicode-property-support-inl-td4701487.html) running under OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

Comment: This is an **excellent** answer. Thanks so much for taking the time to write this; I really appreciate it. I will read all those links and be better informed next time I run into a similar issue.